# Check whether parent table's id used in any referenced tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, foreign-keys, subquery

I got table, let's call it `Department` which his `Primary key (ID)` is used in reference to many other tables as `foreign key`. Is there any way to check for given record `ID` department is used in any relation in other related tables? Asking because I want to just block possibility in my application to remove specific `Department's ID` if this `ID` is already used at elast one time in any reference in other tables.

Comment: Show us at least one of the foreign key declarations.

Comment: If you have foreign keys set up, then the problem is already solved. You can't `DELETE` a row if it's referenced by a foreign key as it would break the foreign key constraint. Unless you have cascading enabled, but then it'll deleted the "foreign" rows too.

Comment: @Larnu cascading is almost everywhere, therefore i want to give users possibility to delete BUT only when specific Department's id is not used in any reference

Comment: That isn't what you ask if your question, @Arie . If you want to block users from deleting rows that are referenced by foreign keys then you shouldn't have cascading enabled.

Comment: @Larnu Why? It's a business requirment.

Comment: It's a business requirement to have cascading enabled but not allow cascading to be used when someone tries to delete a row that would trigger cascading? Are you *sure* about that? That business requirement is flawed if so; it contradicts itself. It's like having a requirement that all staff must wear a blue shirt while at the office, but they are not allowed to wear blue clothing. The two requirements conflict with each other.

Comment: @Larnu It is, nevertheless that;s not the point. I need to find solution on that.

Comment: Then my point stands, disable cascading, it stops people deleting those rows. Having cascading enabled when you **explicitly** don't want those `DELETE` statements to cascade is a design flaw, and the solution is disable the cascading.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Larnu's comment that you should disable `on delete cascade` on the foreign keys. This is the proper way to prevent a parent record from being deleted as long as it has children.

If that can't be done for some reason, then you can use `not exists` subqueries. Assuming that you have three children table, called `child1`, `child2` and `child3`, that refer to parent table `department` through column `department_id`, you can exhibit the departments that are referenced by any of the children with the following query:

```
select d.*
from department d
where exists (select 1 from child1 c1 where c1.department_id = d.id)
   or exists (select 1 from child2 c2 where c2.department_id = d.id)
   or exists (select 1 from child3 c3 where c2.department_id = d.id)
```